# Select the data in the dropdown list RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to get the data from the table in the first list, and next list without selected data from the first list. not use Ajax or NFW?

```
<%= f.select(:room_2, @room_select) %>
<%= f.select(:room_1, @room_select) %>
```

Comment: You question is confusing.  You dont want to to use ajax.  You have a form that has 2 selection lists.  What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: @trh Given: 1 linked table from the database, and 2 field with a dropdown list.
It is necessary to select a value in the first list and the second, while, in the second drop values should be listed in the table except for the value selected from the first list.

Comment: So the first dropdown is something like 'first choice' and the second is 'second choice' - after selecting something in the 'first choice' dropdown, the choices in the second are adjusted.  You don't need AJAX, but you will need javascript.